# Mostrar el formato correcto de una fecha al utilizar el método JsonResult, C#, MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

tengo un problema al tratar de mostrar en mi DataTable el formato de fecha, me lo muestra de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de dar de alta un registro y al seleccionar la fecha, estoy utilizando un datepicker de la siguiente manera:

```js
<script>
    $('#fechaNacimiento').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
    });
</script>
```

Al utilizar Jquery, javascript y ajax para poder llamar al método de mi controlador, llamo a la función desde un botón con el evento OnClick, donde lo estoy realizando de esta manera:

```js
function guardar() {
        Swal.fire({
            title: "Guardando..",
            onOpen: () => {
                swal.showLoading()
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Alumno/guardar",
                    data: {
                        "nombre": $('#txtNombre').val(),
                        "apellidoPaterno": $('#txtApellidoPaterno').val(),
                        "apellidoMaterno": $('#txtApellidoMaterno').val(),
                        "fechaNacimiento": $('#fechaNacimiento').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divBotones").show();
                        if (data["status"] == true) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'success',
                                title: 'Se ha guardado el alumno',
                                showCloseButton: true,
                                allowEnterKey: true,
                                onClose: () => {
                                    $('#id').val(data["datos"]["id"]);
                                    actualizar();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'error',
                                title: 'Oops...',
                                showConfirmButton: true,
                                text: data["mensaje"]
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Oops...',
                            text: request.responseText
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
            onClose: () => {

            }
        });
    }
```

"nombre", "apellidoPaterno", "apellidoMaterno", "fechaNacimiento" en mi base de datos así tengo llamadas las columnas de mi tabla en sql server.

En mi controlador y en mi método guardar estoy utilizando JsonResult como lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```html
public JsonResult guardar(cAlumno objAlumno)
        {
            alumno o = new alumno();
          
            if (objAlumno.id != 0)
            {
                o = db.alumno.Where(a => a.id == objAlumno.id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (o == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("El registro no existe en la base de datos");
                }
                o.nombre = objAlumno.nombre;
                o.apellidoPaterno = objAlumno.apellidoPaterno;
                o.apellidoMaterno = objAlumno.apellidoMaterno;
                o.fechaNacimiento = objAlumno.fechaNacimiento;
                db.alumno.Attach(o);
                db.Entry(o).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                o.nombre = objAlumno.nombre;
                o.apellidoPaterno = objAlumno.apellidoPaterno;
                o.apellidoMaterno = objAlumno.apellidoMaterno;
                o.fechaNacimiento = objAlumno.fechaNacimiento;
                db.alumno.Add(o);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { status = true, mensaje = "Datos guardados", datos = o });
        }
```

y al ver mi respuesta en Json se ve de esta manera:

```js
{
  "status": true,
  "mensaje": "Datos guardados",
  "datos": {
    "id": 8,
    "nombre": "Marco",
    "apellidoPaterno": "Perez",
    "apellidoMaterno": "Gomez",
    "fechaNacimiento": "/Date(794728800000)/"
  }
}
```

Pero me devuelve la fecha de nacimiento en ese formato (/Date(794728800000)/) en la columna de mi DataTable lo he intentado de esta forma pero me muestra la fecha en ese formato:

```js
columns: [
                {
                    data: "id", "render": function (id) {
                        return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar(' + id
                                + ');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="editar(' + id
                                + ');"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "nombre",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return row.nombre + " " + row.apellidoPaterno + " " + row.apellidoMaterno;
                    },
                },
                {
                    "name": "fechaNacimiento",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var fecha = "";
                        if (row.fechaNacimiento) {
                            fecha = row.fechaNacimiento == '0001-01-01T00:00:00' ? '' : row.fechaNacimiento.split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('/');
                        }
                        return fecha;
                    },
                },
```

Pero aun no logro en mostrar la fecha correctamente, espero que me haya explicado, cualquier duda estaré al pendiente.
Saludos.

Comment: La respuesta en el json para una fecha deberían ser solo números, ¿De que tipo tienes tu campo en la base?

Comment: @Charls ¿debe de ser solo números?, El tipo de mi campo es datetime, así lo tengo en mi base

Comment: [Aqui](https://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html) hay una funcion para convertir la fecha String a un formato que pueda manejar javascript.

Comment: @Charls Muchas gracias por la info,lo reviso y lo intentare de esa manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un nuevo objeto con los atributos y darle formato al campo fechaNacimiento:

```
 var dato = new {
      o.nombre,
      o.apellidoPaterno,
      o.apellidoMaterno,
      fechaNacimiento = o.fechaNacimiento.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY")

    };

return Json(new { status = true, mensaje = "Datos guardados", datos = dato });
```